# Функция вывода строк в обратном порядке

Tags: c, strlen

Библиотеки

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
```

функция выводит строки в обратном порядке

```
void print_reverse(char *s) 
{
   size_t len = strlen(s);
```

**Я не понимаю как работает конкретно эта строка и почему S прибавляют к целому числу**

```
   char *t = s + len - 1;
```

**И почему значение t должно быть больше или равно s, ведь t это число а s строка**

```
while ( t >= s )
{
    printf("%c", *t);
    t = t - 1;
}
puts("");
}

int main() {

    char s[] = "ABC";
    print_reverse(s);

return 0;
}
```

Огромная просьба дать ответ на чистом Си.

Comment: Строка в Си это массив символов, последний из которых (символов строки, которых может быть меньше, чем элементов массива) это символ с кодом 0. У каждого элемента массива есть адрес. `char *s` в вашем случае это адрес первого (нулевого, поскольку в Си все индексируем с нуля) элемента массива. `char *t = strlen(s) - 1` -- адрес последнего (перед элементом массива в котором символ с кодом 0). Вот, собственно, и весь background

Comment: последний из которых (символов строки, которых может быть меньше, чем элементов массива) это символ с кодом 0 - я могу его как то вывести через printf чтобы убедится что там символ 0?

Comment: Конечно. `printf("%d\n", s[strlen(s)]);`

Answer (score 3):

> Я не понимаю как работает конкретно эта строка и почему S прибавляют к целому числу : `char *t = s + len - 1;`

указатель `s` хранит в себе адрес начала строки ('указывает' на первый элемент, то есть на 'A' в нашем случае). Когда мы прибавляем `len`, то смещаем этот указатель на `len` элементов, то есть на 3 элемента вперёд.

На что ,в итоге , будет 'указывать' нами объявленный `char *t` при такой инициализации? Правильно, на последний элемент строки, который одинаков для всех строковых литералов, символ **'\0'**, то есть сивмвол конца строки (именно поэтому строки такого рода называются ***нуль-терминированными***). Когда мы отняли единицу, то сместились назад на 1 элемент, и получилось, что 't' теперь имеет адрес, по которому находится символ "C" в строке `s`

Пример : есть строка "Hello, Evgeniy", и я желаю инициализировать ей переменную `s` :

```
char s[] = "Hello, Evgeniy";
```

Теперь я хочу узнать, каков адрес восьмого символа в этой строке. Для этого я просто делаю `s + 8` и получаю адрес первой буквы автора вопроса :)
Обратите внимание : это **адрес**, не само значение. Чтобы получить значение, нужно выполнить т.н. **разыменование**, которое уже у вас есть в цикле для вывода символа (`*t` в `printf("%c", *t);`)

> И почему значение t должно быть больше или равно s, ведь t - это число а s - строка: `while ( t >= s )`

Будьте внимательны : и `t` ,и `s`, как вы уже могли понять - это оба указатели. Когда мы выполняем `t = t - 1;`, то так же, как и в прошлой "арифметике" мы смещаемся на один символ назад.

### Резюмируем:

Функция объявила указатель на `char` , инициализировала его адресом предпоследнего символа исходной строки `s`,  (то есть, 'C') и ,постоянно уменьшая адрес на 1, адрес `t` перемещается на 1 символ к началу исходной строки `s`, пока адрес `t` не будет эквивалентен адресу начала исходной строки `t`.